# Conditionally set CssClass for TemplateField

Tags: c#, .net

I need to conditionally set the CssClass for a Template Field - not for the controls in the Template Field - but for the Template Field itself - so that it renders as:

```
<td class="fred">
```

or

```
<td class="jim">
```

I have been trying things like:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate><%# Eval("ProductName")%></ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ProductType")) == true ? "fred" : "jim" %>' />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and various variations - like trying to set the CssClass dynamically in the  tag - but an error is reported that TemplateField and ItemStyle do not support databinding expressions.

How can I dynamically set the CssClass of a TemplateField?
    enter code here

Comment: you need to do this on *server side*, or you can do it on *client side* too?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing it in the RowDataBound event if I can - I'd like to write it on the .aspx page - not in the code behind.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you are using a GridView control... if this is the case, you would apply the styles within the "RowDataBound" event handler.

Waiting for more information...

Comment: Yes, I have done it the RowDataBound event ... I was hoping to find a way of doing it on the .aspx page